# Subclass of NSOutputStreamer that transparently decrypts data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, encryption, uikit

I have an encrypted stream of data and I have implemented a function more or less similar to:

```
NSInteger DecryptContent(NSInputStream *inputStream,
                         NSOutputStream *outputStream,
                         NSData *key)
{
    NSInteger totalNumberOfWrittenBytes = 0;
    uint32_t recordSequenceNumber = 0;
    NSMutableData *ciphertextInput = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:recordSize];
    NSData *plaintextOutput = nil;
    NSInteger recordDelimiterIndex = -1;
    do {
        CodingHeader *codingHeader = ReadCodingHeaderFromInoutStream(inputStream);
        NSInteger numberOfReadBytes = [inputStream read:ciphertextInput.mutableBytes maxLength:codingHeader.recordSize];
        if (numberOfReadBytes <= 0) {
            LogError(@"Error: Stream should not have ended");
            return -1;
        }
        NSData *actualCiphertextInput = ciphertextInput;
        // Last chunk
        if (numberOfReadBytes != ciphertextInput.length) {
            actualCiphertextInput = [ciphertextInput subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, numberOfReadBytes)];
        }

        NSData *scrambledKey = ScrambleKeyWithRecordSequenceNumberAndSalt(recordSequenceNumber, codingHeader.salt);
        plaintextOutput = Decrypt(actualCiphertextInput, scrambledKey);

        recordDelimiterIndex = FindRecordDelimiterIndex(plaintextOutput);
        if (recordDelimiterIndex < 0) {
            LogError(@"Error: Delimiter not found");
            return -2;
        }

        NSInteger numberOfWrittenBytes = [outputStream write:plaintextOutput.bytes maxLength:recordDelimiterIndex];
        if (numberOfWrittenBytes == -1) {
            LogError(@"Error writing bytes: %@", outputStream.streamError);
            return -3;
        }
        totalNumberOfWrittenBytes += numberOfWrittenBytes;
        recordSequenceNumber++;
    }  while (((uint8_t *)plaintextOutput.bytes)[recordDelimiterIndex] != LastRecordDelimiterByte);
    return totalNumberOfWrittenBytes;
}
```

This is not ideal because it's a blocking function that uses polling on the streams. What's a good approach for adapting this code into an `NSOutputStream` subclass that transparently decrypts data on the fly? Any other async alternatives?

Do I have to override `- (NSInteger)write:(const uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)length` and just manage the decryption using my own intermediary buffer, or is there a better/simpler approach?

If I have to manage my own buffer, not being able to use `NSInputStream` to conveniently read data (and having to use buffer offsets, concatenate several reads into one *encrypted record*, etc.) seems like a huge pain.

Comment: You could make a custom output stream that you schedule on the run loop with `CFWriteStreamScheduleWithRunLoop` to turn the stream processing into a non-blocking operation.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, overriding write:maxLength: is the way you create a custom `NSOutputStream`.  Granted it has been a really long time since I did that so my recollection is fuzzy.